# Routing Help Needed - Site to Site VPN

Tags: vpn, routing, azure, site-to-site-vpn, cisco-vpn

I have successfully established an IPsec Site-to-Site VPN tunnel between our On-Prem network (Gateway, Cisco RV220W) and Azure. However I am hitting a knowledge gap with regards to setting up the routing to allow me to actually send traffic between the two sites.

Here are the details:

## On-Prem:

Local Network: 172.16.0.0

Subnet: 255.255.255.0

## Azure Local Network

Local Network: 172.16.1.0

Subnet: 255.255.255.0

## Azure Virtual Network

Virtual Network: 10.0.0.0

Subnet: 255.255.255.224

Gateway: 10.0.0.32 Subnet 255.255.255.248

I'm unable to route traffic between the two. Connection is stable and established. Azure tells me it has sent a few KB of data but I am stuck with 0 Bytes of data received. This is also confirmed with the IpSec Connection status monitor on the Cisco router.

I have looked and got as far as believe I need to set up a static route between the two subnets but I can't make the Cisco config out. The one I have set up looks a little like this:

- RouteName: LocalToAzure
- Active: Yes
- Private: No
- Destination IP Address: 172.16.1.0
- IP Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
- Interface: WAN(Internet)
- Gatway IP Address: {On-Prem-Public-IP}
- Metric: 2

This doesn't make sense to me as I initial throught I would need to set the Gateway IP as the Azure IP but Cisco won't let me as it needs to be in the subnet for my WAN. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I notice that you have mentioned that you've successfully established a site-to-site VPN, but you haven't listed its interface in your post - basically you want to alter your default gateway to the VPN gateway interface on the Cisco in your configuration as above (not your WAN IP).

Comment: I'm not sure how I define new interfaces. For other devices it seems to be relatively straight forward. http://youtu.be/-57vvLIROxk?t=3m59s

Comment: What I do see is the ability to create a VLAN and then set it to a IP range, but then the Static route gateway can only exist in that subnet...